# cart shipping & tax automatic estimation - one country

Tags: cart, shipping

we are plan to ship only to one default country - so the question is, how to change
Magento CE 1.8 **cart Estimate Shipping and Tax block** - to automatically show (calculate) all shipping methods. By default Magento requires to fill post code - but we will ship only with one country - so the price for any post code is the same.

Any hints how to force Magento to show automatically estimation without filling post code ?

Thank You

Comment: I'v got the same problem as Alex, did you found a solution?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158256)

Answer (score 4):

You can:

1) copy file `app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping.php` in the `app\code\local\Mage\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping.php`

2) define method

```
protected function _getQuote()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
}
```

3) in the function getEstimateRates add

```
$this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
        ->setCountryId($country)
        ->setCity($city)
        ->setPostcode($postcode)
        ->setRegionId($regionId)
        ->setRegion($region)
        ->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$this->_getQuote()->save();
```

where $country and other variables are you pre-defined values.

4) copy the template `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\cart\shipping.phtml` into your custom theme and adjust if if needed.

Comment: Hi, for some reason on first load of the cart `getGroupedAllShippingRates()` is empty, then subsequent visits it isn't. so your code works for all bar the first visit to the cart. Any thoughts?

Comment: Alex, may be it depends on the Magento version and other extensions. You may check debug back trace and share your findings here.  Also, be careful with virtual products bought together with normal products, as they are assigned to different addresses.

Comment: @AlexHadley, any updates on your question?