# Add shipping in cart

Tags: cart, shipping

I want in cart add also and shipping cost:

[image]

Let me know if this possible?

Comment: I see no default shipping calculator at the screen.  If you use it for some address, magento will add the shipping subtotal to the cart automatically.  You may, for example, check how it works and run the same methods with default address on page load

Comment: can you tell me how i can check?

Comment: Take a look at the http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14576/cart-shipping-tax-automatic-estimation-one-country/29609#29609

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a module definition file; in

> app/etc/modules, create the file BTS_Checkout.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <BTS_Checkout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </BTS_Checkout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Create a file:

> app/code/local/BTS/Checkout/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <BTS_Checkout>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </BTS_Checkout>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <bts_checkout>
                <class>BTS_Checkout_Model</class>
            </bts_checkout>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <bts_checkout_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>bts_checkout/observer</class>
                        <method>addShipping</method>
                    </bts_checkout_observer>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_save_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Create Observer.php at :

> app/code/local/BTS/Checkout/Model

```
class BTS_Checkout_Model_Observer {

    private $_shippingCode = 'royalmail';
    private $_country = 'GB';

    public function addShipping($params = null) {
        if (Mage::registry('checkout_addShipping')) {
            Mage::unregister('checkout_addShipping');
            return;
        }
        Mage::register('checkout_addShipping',true);

        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        $quote = $cart->getQuote();

        if ($quote->getCouponCode() != '') {
            $c = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection');
            $c->getSelect()->where("code=?", $quote->getCouponCode());
            foreach ($c->getItems() as $item) { $coupon = $item; }

            if ($coupon->getSimpleFreeShipping() > 0) {
                $quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($this->_shippingCode)->save();
                return true;
            }
        }

        try {
            $method = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
            if ($method) return; // don't overwrite what's already there if we have one set already

            if ($quote->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId() == '') {
                $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId($this->_country);
            }

            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();

            $rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getAllShippingRates();
            $allowed_rates = array();
            foreach ($rates as $rate) {
                array_push($allowed_rates,$rate->getCode());
            }

            if (!in_array($this->_shippingCode,$allowed_rates) && count($allowed_rates) > 0) {
                $shippingCode = $allowed_rates[0];
            }

            if (!empty($shippingCode)) {
                $address = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
                if ($address->getCountryId() == '') $address->setCountryId($this->_country);
                if ($address->getCity() == '') $address->setCity('');
                if ($address->getPostcode() == '') $address->setPostcode('');
                if ($address->getRegionId() == '') $address->setRegionId('');
                if ($address->getRegion() == '') $address->setRegion('');
                $address->setShippingMethod($this->_shippingCode)->setCollectShippingRates(true);
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->save();
            } else {
                $address = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
                if ($address->getCountryId() == '') $address->setCountryId($this->_country);
                if ($address->getCity() == '') $address->setCity('');
                if ($address->getPostcode() == '') $address->setPostcode('');
                if ($address->getRegionId() == '') $address->setRegionId('');
                if ($address->getRegion() == '') $address->setRegion('');
                $address->setShippingMethod($this->_shippingCode)->setCollectShippingRates(true);
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->save();
            }

            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->resetCheckout();

        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addException($e, Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Load customer quote error'));
        }


    }

    public function getQuote() {
        if (empty($this->_quote)) {
            $this->_quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        }
        return $this->_quote;
    }

}
```

This is the [Tutorial](http://www.danneh.org/2010/08/adding-shipping-costs-to-the-cart-automatically-in-magento/)  that I Copied, don't want to share the link alone so added code along

Comment: ok, done, but i not see changes and in cart block not visible Shipping with cost((, what wrong? i use magento 1.8.1.0